# Trying to use AVAudioRecorder, exception when debugging

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, avaudiorecorder

I'm trying to create a simple audio recorder for iphone with a start and stop button using the code below.

Compiling works fine but when I try to debug the program and I press the start button I get Thread 1: Trace, at the line where it says "error: nil];"

Not really sure how to even begin figuring out what that means. This would be the first time using objective-c and xcode by the way.

```
// Start recording or warn that already started
- (IBAction)startButton_clicked:(id)sender {
    if (currentlyRecording == false)
    {
        // Sets recorder settings
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
         setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord
         error: nil];
        NSDictionary *recordSettings =
        [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
         [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
         [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
         [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],
         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey, nil];
        // Determine file name
        NSString *fileDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.wav", fileDir , GetCurrentTime()];
        //debugText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filePath]; // DEBUGGING

         // Prepare recording
         soundFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:filePath];
         AVAudioRecorder *newRecorder =
         [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: soundFileURL
         settings: recordSettings
         error: nil];
         [recordSettings release];
         soundRecorder = newRecorder;
         [newRecorder release];

         // Record
         [soundRecorder prepareToRecord];
         [soundRecorder record];
         currentlyRecording = true;
         headLabel.text = @"Started";
    }

    // if currentlyrecording is already true
    else headLabel.text = @"Already Started";
}


// stops recording or warns that already stopped
- (IBAction)stopButton_clicked:(id)sender {
    if (currentlyRecording == true)
    {
        // Stop recording & clear vars
        [soundRecorder stop];
        soundRecorder = nil;
        currentlyRecording = false;
        headLabel.text = @"Stopped";
    }

    // if currentlyrecording is already false
    else headLabel.text = @"It's not even on!";
}
```

Comment: If you want us to help get rid of your exception, perhaps it would be a good idea to start by telling us what is that you have as an exception?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a similar issue. I get an exception breakpoint on [AVAudioSession sharedInstance] on its own, with no exception in the console window. I do, however, get this in the console output:

```
<com.apple.main-thread> AddPropertyListenerImp posting message to kill mediaserverd (0)
```

I also record in my app, but I'm getting this when my record malfunctions and I restart the app. So this is on a fresh run of the app - but obviously the device has got into a problematic state because of what happened previously.

Hope that helps - I know it's not a direct answer with a solution, but I wanted to shed some more light.